# How do I prove my claim?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Claim -
Let $u$ be any line. Let points $A , B$ not belonging to the line be in the same half plane. Let $P$ be any arbitrary point line $u$. Then $PA+PB=$ minimum $\iff$ $PA=PB$.

This claim in my mind randomly. Can someone please tell if this is true? If yes can you please guide my how to prove this claim? My aim was to get a contradiction to triangle inequalities by assuming another Point $P'$ on line u and prove that $P\equiv P'$ but I am stuck and not reaching anywhere nor am I able to disprove this. Can someone give atleast a hint? I am not asking for a full solution.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: When trying to prove something, it's often useful to consider the extremes. In this case for example, consider A being really close to u and B being much further away from u. In this case, the minimum of PA+PB will be when P is fairly close to A, so PA≠PB. If you want I could probably write you a more rigorous proof if you want/need it

Comment: Yes can you please give the proof? Thanks.

Comment: Consider for simplicity the other case, where $A,B$ are on opposite sides of $u$. Then you can quickly see from the triangle inequality that the point $P$ should be the intersection of $AB$ and $u$. Now use symmetry to deduce how to solve the case with $A,B$ on the same side of $u$. You see that the solution is different from your claim (except for some special cases)

Comment: It is the angles that are equal, not the distances.

Comment: Further to Ivan comment - minimal distance is made by a "ray" going from A and hit B - the point of interception is P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a counterexample, consider $u$ as the $y$-axis, $A=(1,0),$ $B=(2,0),$ and $P=(0,y).$ Clearly, the sum of the lengths is minimized when $y=0,$ but the lengths cannot be equal.

Comment: A counterexample - the simplest  (not always the easiest) way of disproving. Bravo.